# How to switch back to an application without changing its state/activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, task

My application is required to switch back to the previous running apps and I used the following code.

```
RunningTaskInfo currentTask = mRunningTasks.get(appIndex);
String packageName = currentTask.topActivity.getPackageName();
String className = currentTask.topActivity.getClassName();

...

try {
    mContext.startActivity(new Intent().setClassName(
    packageName, className).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
} catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
    Intent launchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager()
        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    mContext.startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

`mContext` is the current `Service`.

This code does allow me to switch to the previous running application but it always go back to the first activity. For example, my previous running application was GMAIL, and I was on the [Email content] page. When I used my code to navigate to GMAIL, it puts me back to the [Email list] page.

What I want is go back to whatever I was doing in that application. The builtin Android Task Manager [by long pressing HOME] can redirect to the previous application without change the page/activity. Could anyone help me fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: I find this post which is the similar question but the solution does not work in my application. My test machine is JB. [Similar question]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853112/launching-an-activity-at-its-current-state

Comment: I found the solution in the AOSP RecentTasksLoader.